# Guest User for Devise using Null Object Pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to implement a `Guest` user within devise, however in doing so `user_signed_in?` always evaluates to `true` how can I get around this?

I can't use `signed_in?` because I have a `Admin` as well as `User` so if I am signed in on the admin panel and then go to the main website it thinks I am signed in if I use `signed_in?`

Here is the code

**Application Controller**

```
def current_user
  if devise_controller?
    @current_user = super
  else
    @current_user ||= super || Guest.new
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<p>Welcome <strong><%= current_user.first_name %></strong></p>
  <ul>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path,
          method: :delete %>
      </li>
     <% else %>
      <li><%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Sign in', new_user_session_path %></li>
     <% end %>
  </ul>
```

**Update**

I have decided to override the `user_signed_in?` method, also the `if devise_controller?` was breaking my tests so I took that out and changed my `ApplicationController` to look like this now.

**Application Controller**

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= super || Guest.new
end

def user_signed_in?
  current_user.is_a? User
end
```

Comment: How are you getting on with that strategy? Is it working out for you?

Comment: Yeah, It hasn't broke yet :)

Comment: Cool, good stuff. I've implemented it myself, only difference is my current_user method looks like this: `super || GuestUser.new`

Comment: I've recently struggled with a similar question and solved it slightly differently based on http://confreaks.tv/videos/railsconf2015-nothing-is-something. In your case, `user_signed_in?` would have been defined as e.g. `current_user.signed_in?`, and the `signed_in?` method would be defined in `User` and `Guest` to return `true` & `false`, respectively. Based on Sandi's talk, the advantage is that this way you no longer own the behaviour but rely on "real" and null objects to respond differently to the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Devise defines `user_signed_in?` here:

```
      def self.define_helpers(mapping) #:nodoc:
        mapping = mapping.name

        class_eval <<-METHODS, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
          def authenticate_#{mapping}!(opts={})
            opts[:scope] = :#{mapping}
            warden.authenticate!(opts) if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
          end

          def #{mapping}_signed_in?
            !!current_#{mapping}
          end

          def current_#{mapping}
            @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :#{mapping})
          end

          def #{mapping}_session
            current_#{mapping} && warden.session(:#{mapping})
          end
        METHODS

        ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
          if respond_to?(:helper_method)
            helper_method "current_#{mapping}", "#{mapping}_signed_in?", "#{mapping}_session"
          end
        end
      end
```

In this case you can just add `!` method to `Guest` class

```
class Guest
  def !
    true
  end
end
```